# How to update another lists multiline rich text field with a current multiline item?

Tags: 2010

I have two lists (same site) and both lists use the Designer 2010 workflow Create or Update List Item to create or update each other.  Both lists contain a field titled Description, which are both set to multiline, rich text.  How do I copy this rich text from one list to the other when an item is created or updated?   I’ve tried adding this function to the current Create or Update List Item but it generates a workflow error.  I need to continue to retain the history of any text added.  Thank  you.

Comment: Can you post the error?

Comment: It’s usually a coercion error.  I can’t seem to reproduce the error at the moment but although there is no error it fails to copy text from one description field to the other.

Comment: By the way, both these fields are set to “Append Changes to Existing Text.” Would this prevent the text from copying or being able to view it in InfoPath 2010?